# Sort 2d array by specific column value in a descending direction

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have any array

```
[
    ['value' => 1, 'label' => 'General'],
    ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'Wholesale Customers'],
    ['value' => 3, 'label' => 'Public Customers'],
    ['value' => 4, 'label' => 'Managers'],
]
```

It's a 2d array; in each index, I have 2 keys: `value` & `label`. Is it possible to sort this array according to `label` (Z-A)?

Desired result:

```
[
    ['value' => 2, 'label' => 'Wholesale Customers'],
    ['value' => 3, 'label' => 'Public Customers'],
    ['value' => 4, 'label' => 'Managers'],
    ['value' => 1, 'label' => 'General'],
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
function myfun($val1, $val2){
    return ($val1["lable"]<$val2["lable"]) ? 0:1;
}

usort($myarr, "myfun");

print_r($myarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP function `array_multisort()` should probably do it for you.  Have a look at [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for more info.

If not, then function `uksort()` will definitely work - as you are supplying your own comparison function for it.  Have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Comment: first thanks for your answer! this is my first question on the net & m glade to see that Kindness is alive! actually i dont define my question clearly so i edit my quest again. Your answer is quite right but when we know we have a same patter for shorting & we dont know how much key inside in this arry so we dont put our compare pattern please m waiting

Comment: @Aleks This answer is provably incorrect.  This answer has been closed by a much more popular canonical.  Your post can be safely removed.  I'd rather not dv.